# What do the numbers in brackets next to my app name in the Xcode console mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

What do the numbers in brackets mean?

```
2012-12-01 10:14:25.769 MyApp[3714:907] -[MyAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]
2012-12-01 10:14:46.058 MyApp[3714:490b] *** -[UIProgressView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2084a050
```

The `3714` and `907`.  Is one the process ID? What's the other? I'm trying to figure out why all the messages ended in `907` until that error on the last line which ended in `490b`.

Comment: rob answered the question, but as an aside, if you want something useful, I always use `NSLog(@"%s ...", __FUNCTION__, ...);` which gives me more meaningful information about where the `NSLog` was generated, including method, and when appropriate, the block or queue. If you want, you can also include the `__LINE__` in there, too.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is nonstandard.  The standard is `__func__`, which is also easier to type. ;^)  If you're using C++, you might want to use the nonstandard `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.  [More info.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Comment: Thank you, yes. I used `__func__` to generate the line above that reads `[MyAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `3714` is the Unix process ID: the value returned by `getpid()`, formatted with `%d`.

The `907` or `490b` is a thread ID: the value returned by `pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self())`, formatted with `%x`.